# Impossible to load pdo driver on Windows Server 2016

Tags: php, apache, pdo, driver, firebird

Im trying to load the pdo driver for firebird database on a windows server 2016 (64 bits).

Configuration is the next :

- Firebird in 32 bits successfully installed.
- Apache 2.4 successfully installed (Apachelounge binary, 32 bits).
- Apache configuration properly set (installed in C:/Apache24)
- PHP 32 bits successfully installed (in C:/PHP) as a module with mod_php (apache handler 2.0).

As a proof :
[phpinfo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOgA4.png)

I can execute the PHP file. Now I want to install the PDO driver in order to have an easy way to connect to the firebird database.

I followed the procedure found on internet (uncomment `extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll` in `php.in` and add `fb.client.dll` in `C/apache24/bin` and `c/php`) and checked if the PDO were correctly installed with this command :

`php -m|findstr -i pdo_`

Which shows me : `PDO_Firebird`

But when I call the phpinfo function in a `test.php` file, it does not show me that any PDO driver has been load. It says :

`PDO drivers : no values.`

which is strange because for PHP the driver is there.
So after some research on internet I tried the following things which didn't work :

- Adding `C/PHP` and `C:/Apche24/bin` in path
- Copy `fbclient.dll` in `C:/Apache/bin`, `C:/PHP` and even in `C:/PHP/ext`
- In `php.ini` uncomment the line `"extension_dir = "ext""`
- For the same line changing value of `"ext"` to `"C:/PHP/ext"`
- Restarting the server after all that

When trying to connect to the firedbird database with a php file I get the error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test3.php:10 
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\test3.php(10): PDO->__construct('firebird:dbname...', 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test3.php on line 10

Of course I could not use PDO driver and use FB/IB extension but I don't want to.

Any help or advice are welcome.

For the fb.client.dll it was just a misspelling, actually the file name is fbclient.dll.

For the php_interbase.dll, I got it in the php/ext folder. I Also tried to add extension=php_interbase.dll in php.ini file, now when I type in cmd : 
php -m|findstr -i pdo_
I got the next things :
 - PDO
 - PDO_Firebird

But still with the phpinfo() function I get the "no value" for PDO drivers even after restarting Apache.

php --ini show this :
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

And the path of the php.ini I edited is C:\PHP\php.ini

Comment: Did you add `fbclient.dll`, or is it really called `fb.client.dll` (which is wrong)? Also do you have the `php_interbase.dll`?

Comment: What is the path of the `php.ini` you edited? And what does `php --ini` show?

Comment: can you try running the pgp-cgi.exe file in your php folder to see if it will show you any errors? It is usually the easiest way to see if your drivers (.dll) are missing and / or if they have an incorrect path set

Comment: I edited the initial post to answer you. For the php-cgi.exe when I run it it just doesn't show anything

Comment: SOLVED ! Guys are going to laugh at me. I was looking for problem everywhere but in fact the problem was so simple that I couldn't see it. In httpd.conf, when adding PHPIniDir "c:/php" at the end of the file, I actually added PHPIniDir "c/php". What a shame ! But finally catched it. Thank you for your help. How to mark this as "Solved" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ! 
Guys are going to laugh at me. I was looking for problem everywhere but in fact the problem was so simple that I couldn't see it. In httpd.conf, when adding PHPIniDir "c:/php" at the end of the file, I actually added PHPIniDir "c/php". What a shame ! But finally catched it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was a little more complex.

Given:

1. Windows10-64/Apache24-64/PHP8-64.
2. php -r "$s=new PDO(dsn, user, pass)" works well without errors.
   The same expression on page throws an exception "driver not found".
3. php -i lists a PDO Firebird driver and the version of the dll.
   phpinfo() on page shows no PDO drivers at all.

The solution is to copy fbclient.dll (64-bit of course) not only in PHP directory but in Apache/bin too!